# Python And 401 response

Tags: python, authentication, passwords

I just wanna ask how to make a connection [user+pass] with A page that give you 401 response.

For example in php its seem like that

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://192.168.1.1/');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.':'.$pass);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Since you apparently already know how to use php's low-level libcurl wrappers, have you looked at the Python wrappers?

Comment: I tryed to search But i didnt find what i want :s

Comment: How did you try to search? Is the problem that you don't know how to search for Python modules, that you don't know a likely name for a module that supplies all those `curl_` functions, or you don't know how to evaluate the different options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the Keyword **Basic HTTP Authentication**.

I do not recommend using 3rd party modules if you won't be going further than doing that. If you will, the `requests` library already suggested is a great choice.

The following example is taken from [the urllib2 docs](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html):

```
import urllib2
# create a password manager
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

# Add the username and password.
# If we knew the realm, we could use it instead of None.
top_level_url = "http://example.com/foo/"
password_mgr.add_password(None, top_level_url, username, password)

handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)

# create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)

# use the opener to fetch a URL
opener.open(a_url)

# Install the opener.
# Now all calls to urllib2.urlopen use our opener.
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something simple, the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install) library is as simple as it could get.  Here is a simple example of [basic authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#basic-authentication) from the docs:

```
>>> requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
<Response [200]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the urllib2 module - http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Answer (score 0):

There are three good options here.

First, you can use [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) (Python 2) or [`urllib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html) (Python 3), which are built in, and pretty easy to use.

Second, you can use an even easier third-party library like [`requests`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests). (Often, code that takes a dozen lines to write with `curl` or `urllib` is a two-liner with `requests`.)

Finally, since you already know how to use php's low-level libcurl wrappers, there are a few different third-party alternatives for Python that are nearly identical. See [this search](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=curl&submit=search), and look through `pycurl`, `pycurl2`, and `pyclibcurl` to see which one feels most familiar.